# Pandas dataframe | groupby plotting | stacked and side by side graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am coming from R ggplot2 background and, and bit confused in matplotlib plot

here my dataframe

```
languages = ['en','cs','es', 'pt', 'hi', 'en', 'es', 'es']
counties = ['us','ch','sp', 'br', 'in', 'fr', 'ar', 'pr']
count = [32, 432,43,55,6,23,455,23]
df = pd.DataFrame({'language': languages,'county': counties, 'count' : count})

    language    county  count
0   en  us  32
1   cs  ch  432
2   es  sp  43
3   pt  br  55
4   hi  in  6
5   en  fr  23
6   es  ar  455
7   es  pr  23
```

Now I want to plot

1. A stacked bar chart where x axis show language and y axis show complete count, the big total height show total count for that language and stacked bar show number of countries for that language
2. A side by side, with same parameters only countries show side by side instead of stacked one

Most of the example show it directly using dataframe and matplotlib plot but I want to plot it in sequential script so I have more control over it, also can edit whatever I want, something like this script

```
ind = np.arange(df.languages.nunique())
width = 0.35
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(ind, df.languages, width, color='r')
ax.bar(ind, df.count, width,bottom=df.languages, color='b')
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_title('Score  y language and country')
ax.set_xticks(ind, df.languages)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
ax.legend(labels=[df.countries])
plt.show()
```

btw, my panda pivot code for same plotting

```
df.pivot(index = "Language", columns = "Country", values = "count").plot.bar(figsize=(15,10))
plt.xticks(rotation = 0,fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Language' )
plt.ylabel('Count ')
plt.legend(fontsize='large', ncol=2,handleheight=1.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

languages = ['en','cs','es', 'pt', 'hi', 'en', 'es', 'es']
counties = ['us','ch','sp', 'br', 'in', 'fr', 'ar', 'pr']
count = [32, 432,43,55,6,23,455,23]
df = pd.DataFrame({'language': languages,'county': counties, 'count' : count})

modified = {}
modified['language'] = np.unique(df.language)
country_count = []
total_count = []
for x in modified['language']:
    country_count.append(len(df[df['language']==x]))
    total_count.append(df[df['language']==x]['count'].sum())

modified['country_count'] = country_count
modified['total_count'] = total_count

mod_df = pd.DataFrame(modified)
print(mod_df)

ind = mod_df.language
width = 0.35 

p1 = plt.bar(ind,mod_df.total_count, width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind,mod_df.country_count, width,
             bottom=mod_df.total_count)

plt.ylabel("Total count")
plt.xlabel("Languages")
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Total Count', 'Country Count'))
plt.show()
```

First,modify the dataframe to below dataframe.

```
  language  country_count  total_count
0       cs              1          432
1       en              2           55
2       es              3          521
3       hi              1            6
4       pt              1           55
```

This is the plot:

[image]

As the value of country count is small, you cannot clearly see the stacked country count.

Comment: thanks, here we have better control in terms of visualization. I got a lot of different example to achieve same, which confused me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, axis = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(x="language",y="count",data=df,ci=None)#,hue='county')
axis.set_title('Score  y language and country')
axis.set_ylabel('Count')
axis.set_xlabel("Language")
```

[image]

```
sns.countplot(x=df.language,data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: I want stacked bar, show show number of country in each language